# Jquery not working with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want assign invoke a Jquery function on click of a button on a Bootstrap 3.0 form.

Simple JQuery function is :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button").click(function(){

  alert("there");

  });
</script>
```

Code the button is :

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</div>
```

I am not getting this alert to pop-up.

Comment: You missing one `});` ? the code should be fine

Comment: whether the buttons are created dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check where have you placed your script.
The code is fine and working(with added }); in script,ofcourse).

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.2.js">

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button").click(function(){

  alert("there");

  });

});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a missing `})`

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("button").click(function () {
        alert("there");
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry I missed last line having }) in my post. It still doesn't work.